# Database backup size increase 

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

There is a problem when I run this query

```
BACKUP DATABASE Test TO DISK = \'C:\\backup\\t1.bak'
WITH NOFORMAT, COMPRESSION, NOINIT, 
NAME = N'Test-Full Database Backup',
SKIP, STATS = 10
```

from SQL Server Management Studio it creates a file with size of 1,186 kb and when I use that code from C# it create a file with size of 11,853kb please anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NOINIT` option you are using is appending to the end of the backup set, so every time you run the script you're adding to the same file, increasing it's size. Please see the Media set options section in the documentation [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

I think calling it from SSMS vs C# is a red herring in this case - you probably just tried it from SSMS first, hence not noticing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a strong feeeling you're appending to your backup media by specifying `NOFORMAT`. Hence the size increase. I usually use `FORMAT` to overwrite the backup media.